# How to select the integer only in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, string, select

I have my table named material

```
pcs_meter
100 m
80 m
```

How can I select the pcs_meter column?
 like:

```
pcs_meter
100
80
```

Comment: `SELECT +SUBSTRING_INDEX(pcs_meter, ' ', 1) FROM material;` ?

Comment: there are several ways you could achieve this... I would suggest storing the values in an array, and affecting those values through php sting functions to truncate out the measurement unit.

Comment: You should **normalize** your database. One of the steps says, keep values atomic. Means, put *100* in one column and *m* in a second column.

Comment: @DanFromGermany I totaly agree

Comment: @DanFromGermany hm.. not sure that has something to do with normalization (well, it may have, hut hard to say what's the reason of current situation)

Comment: @AlmaDo it has, First normal form: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form *A relation is in first normal form if the domain of each attribute contains only atomic values, and the value of each attribute contains only a single value from that domain.* I'm working for a webshop company and that's why we always put currency and value in different columns.

Comment: @DanFromGermany yeah, but in this case we can't be sure what is atomic domain property. It's ambiguous (well, for me)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve that with:

```
SELECT CAST(pcs_meter AS UNSIGNED) FROM material
```

That will work since your value goes first (and MySQL will truncate non-significant symbols from the right). If your field can contain negative values, change `UNSIGNED` to `SIGNED`

Comment: Must have been me, by accident?! Can you hit *edit question* I'll turn this into an upvote.

Comment: Doubt (it was after some certain time) - but ok, improved.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

`SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(pcs_meter,' ', 1) FROM material;`

Comment: this would require every entry to have a space before the measurement unit. If that can be verified as true - than, this would work perfectly.

Comment: Isnt that how you will be storing the data?